# Can you walk me through how constants are initialized in a Gem loaded in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, initialization, rubygems

I am wondering how the initialization process works with Gems. Basically, I ran into an issue today when I tried to call a constant, that lives in my Rails application from a Gem that I have included in my rails project.

The constant is Air::Fly

The constant loads fine from Rails, but the Gem can not load this constant. My goal was to extend the Rails Application class from the context of the Gem, in order to make my code more modular.

How can I load a rails application class from a Gem?

Comment: Make sure the Gem has a runtime dependency properly set for `Air`, so that it is loaded before the gem is loaded.

Comment: Air is a gem, right?  It's not something that's just defined in your Rails app?  You just add it to the gemspec: `s.add_runtime_dependency "air"`.  If it's just something defined in your Rails app, what you're trying to do won't work.  The gem can't depend on your app.  You'd have to refactor it such that you pass in the dependencies at runtime (dependency injection).

Comment: s.add_runtime_dependency did it. ... if you answer this question I will accept your answer. thank you!

Comment: Good to hear :)  I have provided a proper answer for completeness.

Answer (score 2):

Bundler resolves the dependencies of gems by checking the gemspec file for runtime dependencies.  If a gem X's gemspec has `add_runtime_dependency "Y"`, then gem Y will be loaded before gem X.

So, assuming Air is a gem, in your case, you need to add to your gemspec:

```
s.add_runtime_dependency "air"
```

This will ensure it's available for use inside your own gem ;)